# Duda sobre el comando pipe(p) y el acceso a p

Tags: c++

actualmente estoy trabajando en un proyecto que se base en la multi-tarea. Lo que hago es crear un proceso hijo con el comando fork() y en este proceso usar el comando execl para iniciar un ejecutable. La idea, es que el ejecutable pueda transmitir información hacia el proceso padre a través del uso read y write. Como medio para pasar la información quería crear una pila usando el comando pipe(p). Ambos son de c++.

El problema está en que no se como compartir el vector p[2], para que lo pueda incluir tanto en el código que lee, donde lo voy a declarar inicialmente, como para incluirlo a su vez en el código de mi ejecutable para que no me de error.

En el fichero donde declaro los forks, he creado la variable int p[2], y a su vex he hecho pipe(p). Ahora, necesito tener acceso al p, para poder comunicarme a través de pipe.

Había pensado en usar extern int *p, pero me da error ya que no puedo hacer el extern de un puntero. ¿Alguno tiene alguna idea sobre como poder compartir dicho vector? Gracias de antemano.

---

Perdón, este sería una prueba simplificada del código que voy a usar y que tiene el problema.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(){
 int p[2];
 char c[10];
 char skinprof[8];
 char periprof[8];
 char ef_yel_lig_ver[8];
 char ef_inter_ver[8];
 char ef_yel_lig_el[8];
 char ef_inter_el[8];
 char send="Lu";


 pipe(p);
 if(fork()){
 execl("Location of file", (char *) NULL);

 }
 else{
read(p[0],skinprof,7);
write(p[1],send,2);
read(p[0],periprof,7);
write(p[1],send,2);
read(p[0],ef_yel_lig_el,7);
write(p[1],send,2);
read(p[0], ef_inter_ver,7);
write(p[1],send,2);
read(p[0],ef_yel_lig_el,7);
write(p[1],send,2);
read(p[0],ef_inter_el,7);
write(p[1],send,2);
}
 printf("\n Los valores recibidos son: %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s ", skinprof,    periprof, ef_yel_lig_ver, ef_inter_ver, ef_yel_lig_el, ef_inter_el);
 return 0;
}
```

Por otro lado, en el execl, llamo a una GUI que he creado con wxWidgets y que quiero hacer la comunicación entre la GUI y este programa a trvés del pipe.
Muchas gracias por la ayuda de antemano.

Comment: Hola. Por favor, incluye tu código en la pregunta, no sólo la descripción. Nada reemplaza la posibilidad de replicar tu error y revisar tu código

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Según entiendo, tienes dos programas en C. Llamemos al primero "productor.c" (voy a suponer que escribe un dato en la tubería) y al segundo "consumidor.c" (voy a suponer que lee un dato de la tubería, lo procesa de alguna forma, por ejemplo, le suma 1, y lo escribe de nuevo en la tubería, de donde lo lee el productor). Entiendo que compilas ambos para generar los ejecutables `productor` y `consumidor`, respectivamente. El `productor` tras arrancar y crear la tubería, hace `fork()` y `exec()` para cargar `consumidor`. ¿Correcto?

En ese caso, obviamente no puedes desde `consumidor` acceder a la variable `p` creada en `productor`, pues es una variable de un proceso diferente. De nada servirá que la declares como `extern`. Cuando haces `fork()`, el hijo creado sí que tiene acceso (de momento) a la variable `p`, pues es una copia idéntica del padre, incluyendo esa variable que ya había sido inicializada. Pero en el momento que usas `exec()`, la imagen del hijo se destruye (y con ella la variable `p`) para ser reemplazada por la imagen cargada del disco, `consumidor`.

Posibles soluciones:

1. Usa un *named pipe* en lugar de un *unnamed pipe*. Las tuberías con nombre se crean llamando a [`mknod()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mknod.2.html). Estas tuberías aparecen como un fichero en el sistema de archivos (en la carpeta que elijas). Aunque la variable para acceder a ella es diferente en el productor y el consumidor, si ambos abren el mismo "archivo" (*named pipe*) podrán escribir y leer de él para comunicarse.
2. Tras crear el hijo con `fork()` y *antes de ejecutar `exec()`*, redirecciona la entrada y salida estándar del hijo para que apunten al *pipe* que habías creado en el padre. Después haces el `exec()` para cargar el `consumidor`. Todo lo que `consumidor` lea de su entrada estándar, lo estará leyendo en realidad de la tubería, y todo lo que escriba en su salida estándar lo estará escribiendo en realidad en la tubería. Los descriptores de la entrada y salida estándar son el 0 y el 1 respectivamente. No necesitas la variable `p`.

---

### Ejemplo del primer enfoque

#### `productor.c`

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define NOMBRE_TUBERIA "/tmp/tuberia"

int main()
{
  int tuberia;
  char resultado[2];

  // El padre comienza creando la tuberia (la borra antes por si ya existiera)
  unlink(NOMBRE_TUBERIA);
  tuberia = mknod(NOMBRE_TUBERIA, S_IRUSR| S_IWUSR|S_IFIFO, 0);
  if (tuberia<0) {
      perror("mknod");
      exit(2);
  }
  // Ahora lanzará al hijo
  if (fork()==0) {
      execl("./consumidor", "consumidor", NULL);
  }
  // El padre abre la tubería para leer y escribir
  tuberia = open(NOMBRE_TUBERIA, O_RDWR);
  if (tuberia<0) {
      perror("open");
      exit(2);
  }
  // Escribe un dato en la tuberia
  printf("Enviando un 5\n");
  write(tuberia, "5", 1);
  // Esperamos para leer la respuesta del hijo
  sleep(1);
  printf("Esperando respuesta\n");
  read(tuberia, resultado, 1);
  resultado[1]=0; // Añadir terminador
  printf("Resultado: %s\n", resultado);
  return 0;
}
```

#### `consumidor.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define NOMBRE_TUBERIA "/tmp/tuberia"

int main()
{
  int tuberia;
  char resultado[2];
  int dato;

  // El hijo no crea la tubería (ya la creó el padre)
  // Simplemente la abre para leer y escribir
  tuberia = open(NOMBRE_TUBERIA, O_RDWR);
  if (tuberia<0) {
      perror("open");
      exit(2);
  }
  // Leemos un dato, y lo convertimos a entero
  read(tuberia, resultado, 1);
  resultado[1]=0; // Añadir terminador
  dato = atoi(resultado);
  dato++;
  // Convertimos a cadena el resultado y la escribimos en la tubería
  sprintf(resultado, "%d", dato);
  write(tuberia, resultado, 1);
  return 0;
}
```

---

### Ejemplo del segundo enfoque

Se trata aquí de usar tuberías sin nombre, que son las que se crean con `pipe()`. El problema es que la tubería es unidireccional. Puedes usarla para enviar cosas del productor al consumidor o viceversa, pero no ambas cosas a la vez. Para tener comunicación bidireccional, necesitas dos tuberías, lo que complica un poco al productor:

#### `productor.c`

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  int p_escribir[2];  // Hacen falta dos tuberias, una para enviar cosas al consumidor
  int p_leer[2];      // la otra para recibir resultados
  char resultado[2];

  pipe(p_escribir);
  pipe(p_leer);
  // Ahora lanzará al hijo
  if (fork()==0) {
      // el hijo, antes de cambiarse por el consumidor, redirige su
      // entrada y salida estándar
      dup2(p_escribir[0],0 ); // La entrada estándar será el pipe donde escriba el padre
      dup2(p_leer[1], 1); // La salida estándar será el pipe de donde lea el padre
      // Despues deben cerrarse todos los pipes
      close(p_escribir[0]);
      close(p_escribir[1]);
      close(p_leer[0]);
      close(p_leer[1]);
      // Ahora cambiamos el código del hijo, cargando el consumidor
      execl("./consumidor", "consumidor", NULL);
  }
  // El padre sigue por aqui
  // Ha de cerrar los extremos del pipe que usa el hijo
  close(p_escribir[0]);
  close(p_leer[1]);
  // Escribe un dato en la tuberia
  printf("Enviando un 5\n");
  write(p_escribir[1], "5", 1);
  // Esperamos para leer la respuesta del hijo
  sleep(1);
  printf("Esperando respuesta\n");
  read(p_leer[0], resultado, 1);
  resultado[1]=0; // Añadir terminador
  printf("Resultado: %s\n", resultado);
  return 0;
}
```

#### `consumidor.c`

El consumidor en cambio queda muy simple, ya que no sabe nada de los tejemanejes del padre. Se limita a leer de su entrada estándar y escribir en su salida estándar.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  char resultado[2];
  int dato;

  // El hijo simplemente usa su entrada/salida estándar,
  // pues ya las tiene conectadas a la tuberia

  // Leemos un dato de la entrada estándar (0), y lo convertimos a entero
  read(0, resultado, 1);
  resultado[1]=0; // Añadir terminador
  dato = atoi(resultado);
  dato++;
  // Convertimos a cadena el resultado y la escribimos en la salida estándar (1)
  sprintf(resultado, "%d", dato);
  write(1, resultado, 1);
  return 0;
}
```

## Resultado

Cualquiera de los dos enfoques produce el mismo resultado. El padre, tras lanzar al consumidor, escribe un 5 en la tubería, espera un segundo y lee de la tubería mostrando el resultado (que ha sido puesto allí por el consumidor). Esto se vería en el *shell*:

```
$ ./productor
Enviando un 5
Esperando respuesta
Resultado: 6
```